# Chrome CORS troubles

Tags: google-chrome, cors

My node backend is set on Heroku, React frontend on Netlify. On firefox everything works good but on chrome I can login (post request) and then I can't move on my page cuz cors policy blocks my get requests to the server.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxx.herokuapp.com/api/fetchPurchasedPrizes' from origin 'https://xxx.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My backend cors setup

```
    app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'xxx.netlify.app',
  }),
);
```

On localhost both browsers worked good.

Comment: `xxx.netlify.app` is not an origin. Did you mean `https://xxx.netlify.app`?

Comment: Yeah, i mean with https. I found a solution, I just had to add { sameSite: 'none', secure: true} to my cors setup.

Comment: Cool. Don't hesitate to write your own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution, I just had to add

```
cookie: {
  sameSite: 'none',
  secure: 'true',
},
```

to my session config.

Comment: You can also accept your answer, to mark the question as resolved.